# MySQL 5.6.16 DATETIME field DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not working

Tags: php, mysql, macos, datetime, default-value

I have two Macs running homebrew installed (MySQL 5.6.16 and PHP 5.5.8), my laptop (10.7) and the server (10.9 server). They are running identical source code. I ran mysql_install_db and mysql_upgrade on both machines yesterday.

(records out of sync)
Here is the diff output from show create table individuals:(macbook left, server right)

```
< ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=128928 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
---
> ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=128432 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

They have identical table definitions except for autoincrement.

Here is the diff output from show variables: (macbook left, server right)

```
35c35
< datadir       /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/
---
> datadir       /usr/local/mysql/data/    
82c82
< hostname      Bradley-Slavik-MacBook.local
---
> hostname      www.opinionwizard.com
212c212
< key_buffer_size       268435456
---
> key_buffer_size       402653184
326c326
< pid_file      /var/mysql/mysql.pid
---
> pid_file      /usr/local/mysql/data/www.opinionwizard.com.pid
335c335
< pseudo_thread_id      52
---
> pseudo_thread_id      5
366c366
< server_uuid   6356280a-847d-11e3-a2cd-3912ad30e5ec
---
> server_uuid   51d7bac8-e421-11e2-8d20-1d8e718a624d
388c388
< slow_query_log_file   /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql/Bradley-Slavik-MacBook-slow.log
---
> slow_query_log_file   /usr/local/mysql/data/www-slow.log
428c428
< timestamp     1392999311.730679
---
> timestamp     1393006691.207529
441c441
< version_compile_os    osx10.7
---
> version_compile_os    osx10.9
```

(Show global variables had the same differences, with pseudo_thread_id and timestamp missing)

However, when I save a record on my macbook without specifying the enter_date, it is correctly set to the current_timestamp. On the server, I receive this error:

```
Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' for column 'enter_date' at row 1
```

Here is the entire message in case anyone can read it:

```
{"status":"Internal Server Error","code":500,"text":"SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' for column 'enter_date' at row 1","trace":[{"file":"\/Users\/ow_dev\/fatfree-3.2.0\/lib\/DB\/SQL.php","line":143,"function":"execute","class":"PDOStatement","type":"->","args":[]},{"file":"\/Users\/ow_dev\/fatfree-3.2.0\/lib\/DB\/SQL\/Mapper.php","line":346,"function":"exec","class":"DB\\SQL","type":"->","args":["INSERT INTO `individuals` (`last_edited_by_employee_id`,`last_edited_date`,`opt_in_date_time`,`phone_count`,`household_id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`email_address`,`password`,`birthdate`,`adult_contact`,`language_id`,`allow_household_edit`,`entered_by_employee_id`,`enter_date`,`gender`,`marital_status_id`,`education_id`,`work_status_id`,`political_id`,`ethnicity_id`,`industry_id`,`headquarters`,`work_title`,`company_name`,`company_email`,`company_address1`,`company_address2`,`company_city`,`company_state`,`company_zip`,`company_country`,`company_revenues_id`,`company_local_employees_id`,`company_total_employees_id`,`status`,`status_date`,`inactive_reason_id`,`defer_to_date`,`times_no_showed`,`times_canceled`,`times_late`,`times_not_qualified`,`times_excused`,`times_used`,`sign_up_category`,`other_inactive_reason`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)",{"1":[2,1],"2":["2014-02-21 12:17:21",2],"3":["0000-00-00 00:00:00",2],"4":[0,1],"5":[52992,1],"6":["Chloe",2],"7":["Hans",2],"8":["",2],"9":["",2],"10":["2008-12-17",2],"11":[66400,1],"12":[1,1],"13":["No",2],"14":[0,1],"15":["CURRENT_TIMESTAMP",2],"16":["Female",2],"17":[0,1],"18":[0,1],"19":[0,1],"20":[0,1],"21":[1,1],"22":[0,1],"23":[0,1],"24":["",2],"25":["",2],"26":["",2],"27":["",2],"28":["",2],"29":["",2],"30":["--",2],"31":["",2],"32":[0,1],"33":[0,1],"34":[0,1],"35":[0,1],"36":[2,1],"37":["2014-02-21 12:17:21",2],"38":[0,1],"39":["0000-00-00",2],"40":[0,1],"41":[0,1],"42":[0,1],"43":[0,1],"44":[0,1],"45":[0,1],"46":["consumer",2],"47":["",2]}]},{"file":"\/Users\/ow_dev\/fatfree-3.2.0\/lib\/DB\/Cursor.php","line":192,"function":"insert","class":"DB\\SQL\\Mapper","type":"->","args":[]},{"file":"\/Users\/ow_dev\/OpinionWizard\/libs\/Individual.php","line":611,"function":"save","class":"DB\\Cursor","type":"->","args":[]},{"file":"\/Library\/Server\/Web\/Data\/Sites\/dev.opinionwizard.com\/individualSave.php","line":49,"function":"saveIndividual","class":"individual","type":"->","args":[]}]}
```

I can see the 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' being passed as parameter 15, which is correct.

I have noted issues previously where the server has been much pickier than my macbook about getting just the right type of data. I have been updating my code to be much more strict and migrating the changes to production. This time the DEFAULT value is supposed to be supplying the value, and appears to be supplying the value. I had not taken a close look at the configuration before, and I assumed that I had some more strict setting on the production server that was not present on my macbook, but the only difference that I find plausible is the version of the operating system (10.7 vs 10.9). I have restarted both database server and apache several times over the last day, so all the settings in the configuration files should have taken effect.

Is there a PHP setting that I should be looking at? Some other command in mysql to get configuration other than show variables? What else should be examined in the environments that could cause the production server to be less forgiving or flexible?

Comment: I don't think you can set a `DATETIME` field's default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (it only works for `TIMESTAMP` fields).

Comment: Thanks jraede. According to several stackoverflow questions and official mysql documentation at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-type-defaults.html, support was added in 5.6.5, and this blog - http://shankargopal.blogspot.com/2013/03/mysql-566-timestamp-columns-and-default.html. If it should not work, then it should not work on either machine, unless I have missed something obvious.